# How to delete keyspace from grakn console?

Tags: vaticle-typedb

i want to delete a keyspace present at my grakn console.

I think since grakn uses cassandra at backend for storing data i need a way to access cassandra to drop the keypsace.
help

Answer (score 3):

when your enter the console， type

clean

confirm

Answer (score 3):

As of Grakn 1.7.0 you can now (in the grakn console) type:

```
keyspace list
```

to show all keyspaces

and `keyspace delete [name]` to delete a keyspace from the console directly.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the console using: 
`./grakn console -k [keyspace-name]`
then enter the command: 
`clean`
You will be prompted to confirm your operation: 
`confirm`